# Prove that there are exists two denumerable sets $A and B$ such that ${ab| a \in A, b \in B}$ is enumerable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability

Prove that there are exists two denumerable sets $A$ and $B$: {$a*b| a \in A, b \in B$}

Set is denumerable if we have an algorithm which can output all elements from this set in finite time.
Set is enumerable if we can't find this algorythm

Comment: What's the difference between "denumerable" and "enumerable"?  Are $A,B$ suppose to be sets of real numbers or something like that?

Comment: Please edit your post.  The body of  your post doesn't even ask a complete question.  More importantly, include your efforts.  What have you tried?

Comment: @lulu added smth